# How to set env variables in Makefile to run tests?

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm trying to create a `Makefile` to run my tests. I have to set `DATABASE_URL` variable before running the tests but it looks like it doesn't work.

Here's my `Makefile`

```
IP := $(docker-machine ip default)
DATABASE_URL := "postgres://postgres@$(IP)/postgres"
test: 
    @echo ${DATABASE_URL}
    py.test tests
```

I get error something like this

```
E   psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
E       Is the server running locally and accepting
E       connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

If I set `DATABASE_URL` directly from bash I can run the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should export DATABASE_URL as described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#index-exporting-variables).

```
export DATABASE_URL := "postgres://postgres@$(IP)/postgres"
```

The `echo ${DATABASE_URL}` is resolved by make and not by shell. Just try `env | grep DATABASE_URL` and you will get and error as long as `DATABASE_URL` is not exported.

The behaviour you expected (exporting all variables) can be achieved by the `export` command without parameters.